# How to change the username given by "whoami" in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts

When I first installed Windows 10, I chose my username to be ***firstname lastname***. However, Windows decided to convert my account from a local one to a Microsoft one. Therefore, I converted it back to a local account and changed the username to ***firstname*** (since it has to be different), and then changed the username in Control Panel once again to ***firstname lastname***.

All is good so far. C:\Users<username> is still ***firstname lastname*** since that's what I chose during Windows setup. But when I type in *whoami* in Command Prompt, it gives:

`desktop-xxxxxxx\firstname`

Is there a way to change it so that *whoami* will give

`desktop-xxxxxxx\firstname lastname`

Comment: Try changing the profile name  (https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/89060-change-name-user-profile-folder-windows-10-a.html)   . Truly, I find it best just to leave the profile name as is. No harm in doing that.

Comment: How you would do this is use prompt for a profile name when you unlink a local account from a Microsoft Account.  The control panel does not make the necessary changes.

Comment: @John I first decided to do this due to a licensing issue with a program, but reinstalling and reactivating it resolved it. Like you said, maybe it's not worth the work.

Comment: @Ramhound Do you know of a quick CMD command to change the profile name? The one linked by John seems more involved.

Comment: @Skipher - The method I suggested takes less than 1 minute to perform.  I am unware of any command that does what I described in my earlier comment.  I don't believe that command to actually exist, since the ability to change your profile name and the directory that was used, didn't actually exist until Windows 8 which supported Microsoft Accounts.  *Any method that existed or exists is a combination of what basically can be described as hacks.*

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion. I had already unlinked my local account from the Microsoft account. Does that mean John's method is the only way?

Comment: I am suggesting you repeat the process.  If you want `John Smith` to be the profile name, then when prompted for a profile name, provide that name.  Whatever, value is provide will become the name of the directory that contains the profile.  A word of caution, most applications don't handle spaces in a profile name, so you might not actually want a space in your profile name.

Comment: It may also be worth following the process I pointed to earlier on, or just ignore the name and use as is.

Answer (score 3):

Press WIN + R.
type "netplwiz" and Enter (User Accounts dialog box will appear)
Select your account and Click Properties.
Change Username & Apply OK etc.
Restart Your Computer.

Regards,
J Wick

Answer (score 0):

This method worked for me on Windows 10.

Follow the steps:

- Press <kbd>WIN</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>
- Type `netplwiz` and <kbd>Enter</kbd> (User Accounts dialog box will appear)
- Select your account and click **Properties**
- Change username and click apply or ok
- Restart your computer

*Note: if you open control panel right after changing username, it will give you a weird error. Don't panic. Just restart it will be fine.*